# Updating records with regexp match (all matches)

Tags: mysql, regex

I use the following query to get the records that their `username` starts with 97:

```
select username,id from mdl_user where username regexp '^(97)';
```

This gives me a bunch of records like

```
| 9798432                                     |  7122 |
| 9798905                                     | 15490 |
| 9799106                                     | 15236 |
```

Now to want to get the value of `username` for that `id` and copy that to another field, `idnumber`, for the same `id`, if `idnumber` is zero, for all `id`s that it finds. My idea is:

```
UPDATE mdl_user 
SET idnumber = (SELECT username FROM mdl_user WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM mdl_user WHERE username REGEXP '^(97)') 
AND idnumber=0
```

I am not sure if that single query works for all matches or not. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the subquery. Put the `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` query. It will then copy the column from the same row.

```
UPDATE mdl_user
SET idnumber = username
WHERE username REGEXP '^97'
AND idnumber = 0
```

BTW, `username LIKE '97%'` will probably be more efficient if it's indexed; I don't think MySQL makes much use of indexes when processing regular expressions.